# Is there any situation when col.insert doesn't send any error but the document(s) is (are) not inserted?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I see often the following code snippet:

```
collection.insert({"some": "data"}, function (err, inserted) {
   if (err) { /* do something */ return; }
   if (!inserted || !inserted.length) {
       console.error("Nothing inserted ...");
       return;
   }
   /* do something */
});
```

Is the second `if` really required?

When the `insert` method doesn't send an `err` in callback and `inserted` variable is `undefined`, `null` or something like this?

Comment: Where have you seen that? That's unusual.

Comment: Hmm no the driver will either return a "false" success due to edge case within a replica set or error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument passed to the callback of `insert` *can* be `null` (with `err` being `null` as well), according to [the sources](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/24c82b7d8b5a5e5bb45f64124ea1a0ab6fc71163/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js#L100), when you're using MongoDB 2.6 (or higher), the write concern is 0 and there's a callback function passed.

I'm not running 2.6, so can't test this myself:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/demo?w=0', function(err, db) {
  db.collection('test').insert({ foo : 'bar' }, function(err, inserted) {
    console.log('I', inserted);
  });
});
```

However, `inserted` would not be an array in this situation, but plain `null`. So the check would have to be `if (! inserted) { ... }`, and it wouldn't be an error (setting the write concern to 0 means you're just not interested in knowing if the insert failed or not).

Comment: *However, `inserted` would not be an array in this situation, but plain `null`.* - I don't agree. I got this output: `I [ { foo: 'bar', _id: 52c997cbf228d47261d336ea } ]` - So `inserted` **is** an array. And yes, if `inserted` can be `null` then we must check `if (!inserted || !inserted.length) { /* no inserted document */ }`. When can `inserted` be `null`, `false`, `undefined`, or an empty array after a *succesful* (no `err`) insert?

Comment: @IonicăBizău if you take a look at the link I posted, you'll notice `return callback(null, null);`. So not an array, but plain `null`. Also, this should only happen on MongoDB 2.6 (or rather 2.5, which is the version that will eventually be released as 2.6, but is still in development).

Comment: Yes, I can see `return callback (null, null)` but when is this happening? When is the second argument `null`?

Comment: @IonicăBizău when the write concern is set to 0, meaning that you're telling the MongoDB driver that you're not interested in knowing if the insert worked okay or that it failed. A bit of a fire-and-forget mode, so to speak.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Since the write concern is usually setup in another place in the code (not there where insert is called), writing the code like that, assures that the code will not break when the write concern becomes `0`.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need second `if` for `insert()` callback. But we may need second `if` for `update()` callback.

I think the author of that code confused `insert()` with `update()` (?)

**Insert** [document link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#insert)

```
collection.insert({"some": "data"}, {safe: true}, function(err, records){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(records);
});
```

*Side note: According to document, we must pass {safe: true} to get the `err param` in `callback`, because it is default to `false`. But I feel like it is `true` by default for me (including production mode)*

**Update** [document link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#update)

```
collection.update({"some": "data"}, function (err, count) {
    if(err) throw err;

    // SECOND IF        
    if(!count) {
        console.log('NOTHING UPDATED');
    }
});
```

Comment: After reading documents, and make some tests with node.js I did not found any case that second if will be false, any other opinion are welcome